# (Help) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    get_odd_palindrome_at('racecar', 3)
  File "C:\Users\musar\Documents\University\Courses\Python\Assignment 2\palindromes.py", line 48, in get_odd_palindrome_at
    for i in range(string[index:]):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

---

I want to use the value index refers to but how do I do that?

Comment: What do you think the problem might be? What have you tried so far? What have you searched for? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from your error than the 'index' variable is a string, not an int.  You could convert it using int().

```
index = int(index)
for i in range(string[index:]):
```

Now, string[index:] will also be an string.  So you would need to convert that too:

```
>>> string = "5"
>>> range(string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
>>> range(int(string))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

That's assuming that string[index:] only contains a number.  If that's not always the case, you can do something like:

```
# 'index' contains only numbers
index = int(index)
number = string[index:]
if number.isdigit():
    number = int(number)
    for i in range(number):
```

From [the Wikipedia article on Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)):

> Python uses duck typing and has typed objects but untyped variable names. Type constraints are not checked at compile time; rather, operations on an object may fail, signifying that the given object is not of a suitable type. Despite being dynamically typed, Python is strongly typed, forbidding operations that are not well-defined (for example, adding a number to a string) rather than silently attempting to make sense of them.

In this case, you try to pass a string to range().  This function waits for a number (a positive integer, as it is).  That's why you need to convert your string to int.  You could actually do a bit more of checking, depending on your needs.  Python cares for types.

HTH,

Comment: index is actually a parameter in my function and it refers to a int which refers to the index value of string. I want to use the value in the parameter as an index, how do I do it?                                                   def get_odd_palindrome_at(string, index):
    '''(str, int) -> str

    Return the longest odd-length palindrome in the string that is centered at the specified index.

Comment: From the exception you quoted (for i in range(string[index:]):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer), it seems to me that 'index' actually contains a string, not an int.  You should check that you pass an integer to your function.  Note that a string can contain numbers in Python (and in most languages), var = "3" creates a string... not an integer.  Sorry if that sounds obvious, but sometimes one forgets that.

Comment: Or a shorter answer, your first line in your function could convert your index: index = int(index)   . But it's much better to check the type of the data you send to the function.  If your function expects a string and an int, then a string and an int you should send it ;) .

Comment: I typed in >>> get_odd_palindrome_at('racecar', 3) and I got the error, 3 seems to be an int. I tried to all index in my function body to int(index) but still getting same error

Comment: Okay, sorry, I was trying with Python 2.X and not getting your error.  So the error you have is not because index is a string, after all, but because string[index:] is a string.  If string is 'racecar', index is 3, then string[3:] is 'ecar'.  And you cannot use range with a string... you have to use it with a number.

Comment: I don't know what your function does (to be honest, I'm not that good with math).  If you want to browse every character in your string, you could do something like for character in string[index:]:   . Remember, string[index:] returns the string from the letter at index (position 3 in that example) until the end of the string.  Alternatively, if you want to generate numbers fro 0 to index, you could use for i in range(index) (but then, why the string?)  I hope this helps you find the problem.